# problem customising navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle

Tags: iphone, navigationcontroller, navigationbar

i read thru the whole forum maybe im doing something wrong
any help would be great

tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
 tabController.delegate = self;
    [tabController setViewControllers:
     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
      //[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[SearchTableViewController alloc] init] autorelease]] autorelease],
      //[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[SearchPhotosViewController alloc] init] autorelease]] autorelease],
   //[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[SearchPhotosViewController alloc] init] autorelease]] autorelease],
      //[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[SearchPhotosViewController2 alloc] init] autorelease]] autorelease],
   [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[crap2 alloc] init] autorelease]] autorelease],
   [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[crap3 alloc] init] autorelease]] autorelease],
   [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[crap alloc] init] autorelease]] autorelease],
      nil]];
 //tabController.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

//tabController.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
 //tabController.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
 //tabController.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
tabController.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    [window addSubview:[tabController view]];

Answer (score 0):

For NavigationController, try:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

For a Toolbar, try:

```
[toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: i have tried that. i get 
request for member 'navigationController' in something not a structure or union

ive also tried it in the individual m files:
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

but unfortunately nothing happens

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a toolbar instead of a navcontroller?

Comment: Hmmmm... If I do, then how do I change that to black?

Comment: See edited answer. And if all else fails, create a XIB and edit your toolbar in Interface Builder.

Comment: i am currently using a xib, when i add a navigationbar
i get 2 navigation bars, one on top of the other.

im pretty sure its some kind of navigationbar
i actually init it at m file
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
  self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blah.png"];
        self.title = @"blah";
  
 }
    return self;
 
}
so its beginning to confuse me.

Comment: anyone who can help i will be very very grateful, sample project at http://www.geckus.com/geckus_files.zip
still have the problem of changing the navigation style or colour.